Is どっちでもって どっちでもいい?
A character get asked what which teams he wants to join and he answers this.
俺はどっちでもって.
From context I can gather it's "どっちでもいい"? But why is it written like this?

Are you familiar with って as a contraction of と言って? Beyond that, it's hard to say anything much without more context in terms of the Japanese text.

It seems this question can be edited provide more clarity
